# TypeError: object of type 'WebElement' has no len() error while looping for all img tags in a web page using selenium webdriver in Python?

Tags: python, list, selenium, web-scraping, getattribute

Currently using selenium in python and was trying to for loop after locating element by "img" tags in whole webpage. I am trying to save all the urls and img names to my 2 arrays.

```
imgurl = []
imgname = []
allimgtags = browser.find_element_by_tag_name("img")

for a in len(allimgtags):
    imgurl.append(wholeimgtags.get_attribute("src"))
    imgname.append(wholeimgtags.get_attribute("alt"))
```

but i am getting this error in the terminal. How do i save the sub urls and names to my 2 arrays?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrpy_selenium.py", line 31, in <module>
    for a in len(wholeimgtags):
TypeError: object of type 'WebElement' has no len()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using:

```
find_elements_by_tag_name(name)
```

(Notice plural)

This will return you a List of elements, then you can loop throw them.

https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_elements_by_tag_name

Answer (score 0):

Try to get all the img tags and loop through them.

```
allimgtags  = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("img")
for img in allimgtags:
    imgurl.append(img.get_attribute("src"))
    imgname.append(img.get_attribute("alt"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
TypeError: object of type 'WebElement' has no len()
```

...implies that in your program you have invoked `len()` method on a [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139), where as `len()` method is used to get the length of the given *string*, *array*, *list*, *tuple*, *dictionary*, etc.

---

### Solution

To invoke `len()`, instead of `find_element_by_tag_name()` you need to use `find_elements_by_tag_name()` which would return a *list*. So your effective code block will be:

```
imgurl = []
imgname = []
allimgtags = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("img")
for imgtag in allimgtags:
    imgurl.append(imgtag.get_attribute("src"))
    imgname.append(imgtag.get_attribute("alt"))
```

---

### Alternative

As an alternative to print the *src* and *alt* attributes, you can use the following lines of code:

- `src`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("src") for my_elem in browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("img")])
  ```
- `alt`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("alt") for my_elem in browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("img")])
  ```